# Using get[int index] and set[int index] to update values in an array

Tags: vala

I am trying to provide a way to update a value inside an array in vala, for example `myClass.Channels[10]=15`, however, I can't find a way to do this in vala. The following works in C#, and I would have assumed that vala was similar.

```
private int[] _channels;

public int[] Channels
{
    get[int index]
    {
        return _channels[index];
    }
    set[int index]
    {
        _channels[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know if a way of doing this exists?

Comment: I don't know Vala, but I'm guessing `return Channels[index];` should be `return _channels[index];`.

Comment: @hammar of course, thank you, although the errors are happening on the `get[int index]` and the `set[int index]` lines so that's still not fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vala supports Indexers, see http://live.gnome.org/Vala/ValaForCSharpProgrammers#Indexers

It can only be used on class, not on arrays.

If that's really useful for you, you should open a bug (and even provide a patch!)

Comment: Thanks for that, it's a shame that it's not possible, but that way of doing it actually fits better with my aims than doing it with arrays.